# Null Pointer Exception when calling HashMap.put

Tags: java, android, parameters, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a class with a HashMap Defined:

```
class AccomplishmentsOutbox {

    HashMap<String, Boolean> mAchBools = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(){{
        put("CgkIlezvppMIEAIQAg", false);
        }
    };
}
```

Inside my Activity Class, I have added:

```
AccomplishmentsOutbox mOutbox = new AccomplishmentsOutbox();
```

Then, in a method, I try to set the HashMap boolean to true:

```
public void onUnlockAchievement(String achievementID) {
    mOutbox.mAchBools.put(achievementID, true);
}
```

This line throws a Null pointer exception, when I pass the same String ID (CgkIlezvppMIEAIQAg) as a parameter. Are there any obvious reasons this is causing an error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `mOutbox`? Has it been initialized?

Comment: Please add code for `mOutbox` initialization, and how is `mAchBools` exposed outside since i don't see it as public.

Comment: I forgot to add that inside my Activity Class, I have added: AccomplishmentsOutbox mOutbox = new AccomplishmentsOutbox();

Comment: First of all I would not make mOutbox.mAchBools public, i'll use accessor methods to add or remove content out of the hashmap. Also, do a null check before you try to add or remove the values from the hashmap

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check values of `mOutbox` and `mOutbox.mAchBools`

Comment: I added a breakpoint but it only reports the "AchievementID" Variable, I can't see anything for mOutbox or mOutbox.mAchBools

Comment: You are not initializing mOutbox before using it.  This is a poor question without enough detail, for a common error.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because `mOutbox` has not been initialized

Make sure you're doing a `mOutbox = new AccomplishmentsOutbox();` somewhere

Comment: I forgot to add that inside my Activity Class, I have added: AccomplishmentsOutbox mOutbox = new AccomplishmentsOutbox();

Comment: Or maybe `mAchBools` changed after `<init>`

Comment: What do you mean? I am lost trying to find the reason for this null pointer exception.